# integrating data into DB shows question marks as value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset named "supplier_dim" in an excel sheet, and one of the columns "SUPPLIER NAME"  has names in Russian [supplier_name_data_input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9lBY.png)

So when I tried creating a table to integrate data into:

```
create table supplier_DIM 
(
    ID_supplier int primary key identity (1,1),
    supplier_name nvarchar(50),
    supplier_code varchar(50)
)
```

Then I inserted data into this table:

```
insert into supplier_DIM (supplier_name, supplier_code) 
values ('Шпаркасе Лизинг ДОО', 'DC000325')
```

I get this result when I select all columns:

[image: out_put]

How can I fix the question mark value problem?

Comment: You need to be using an `nvarchar` *not* a `varchar`.

Comment: Also, please don't tag spam. MySQL and SQL Server are completely different products. These appears to be SQL Server, due to your use of `IDENTITY`. I'm also not sure what the above it about SSIS.

Comment: @Larnu I tried using 'nvarchar' instead of 'varchar' still not working  also sorry for using SSIS and MySQL tags

Comment: Then you were still using a `varchar` somewhere, if you got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

`'Шпаркасе Лизинг ДОО'`  is a varchar literal, and will not preserve the characters in a database without a special collation.  Instead use an nvarchar literal, eg

```
supplier_DIM (supplier_name,supplier_code) values (N'Шпаркасе Лизинг ДОО','DC000325')
```